# Background in a css stylesheet

Tags: html, css, background

So I'm trying to add a background using a CSS stylesheet, but the image doesn't show up no matter how I format it, is there something I'm doing wrong?

[main.hmtl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx90e.png)

[main.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUZFb.png)

Comment: I would use code blocks or the SO snippet function not just links to the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems image name  is different in css file. Try coping image name and paste the correct one in css file. "backround-example.jpg" need to give in css file

Comment: next time use a name like: "bg-1" or "bg-example" to minimize typing errors which always happen.

Comment: try copying the image path and paste where you require.  From starting I too suffer this type of problem multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Use `background:` property instead of `background-image`
try this

```
background:url("Path to Your Image") no-repeat center center/cover;;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your syntax is wrong... You used ' not "